# How to replace empty values with reference to another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have 2 data frames. One is reference table with columns: code and name. Other one is list of dictionaries. The second data frame has code filled up but some names as empty strings. I am thinking of performing 2 for loops to get to the dictionary. But, I am new to this so unsure how to get the value from reference table.

Started with something like this:

```
for i in sample:
    for j in i:
        if j['name']=='':
            (j['code'])
```

I am unsure how to proceed with the code. I think there is a very simple way with .map() function. Can someone help?

Reference table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2TzZ.png)

Edit needed table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3aTY.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in this particular case you're using Pandas only to work with Python data structures. If that's the case, it would make sense to ditch Pandas altogether and just use Python data structures - usually, it results in more idiomatic and readable code that often performs better than Pandas with `dtype=object`.

In any case, here's the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

sample_name = pd.DataFrame(dict(code=[8, 1, 6],
                                name=['Human development',
                                      'Economic managemen',
                                      'Social protection and risk management']))

# We just need a Series.
sample_name = sample_name.set_index('code')['name']

sample = pd.Series([[dict(code=8, name='')],
                    [dict(code=1, name='')],
                    [dict(code=6, name='')]])


def fix_dict(d):
    if not d['name']:
        d['name'] = sample_name.at[d['code']]
    return d


def fix_dicts(dicts):
    return [fix_dict(d) for d in dicts]


result = sample.map(fix_dicts)
```

Comment: the code you provided is hard coding the data. The reference table I mentioned is a result of another piece of code. So, do you want to convert the dataframe back to dict?

Comment: I'm hardcoding the data only because I have no idea about the code that created it in the first place. It's just an example after all. I would convert everything to dicts, yes. If you're talking about reassigning `sample_name` above, you can just use a different name.